# How to train a net for recognize the number

Tags: machine-learning

Documentation have some examples about `MNIST`.But those image have same image.I make some trained data

```
data = RandomSample[
   Catenate[
    Thread /@ 
     Tuples[Function[font, 
         Image[Rasterize[Style[ToString[#], FontFamily -> font], 
             ImageResolution -> 150]] & /@ Range[21]] /@ 
        RandomSample[$FontFamilies, 10] -> {Range[21]}]]];
```

These images have difference size.And I don't know this trained net will face which size image.But it should recognize it.And I don't know it will face which font,so I make some random font to train it. There is a try about how to build layers to train it

```
net = NetChain[{ImageAugmentationLayer[{12, 12}, 
    "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {15, 15}}], 
    "Output" -> NetDecoder["Image"]], FlattenLayer[], 21}, 
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[21]}]]
```

[image]

But I don't know the error information mean what..

```
NetTrain[net, data]
```

[image]

Comment: Try this net: `NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"]`. And if you want to retrain it on your own data: `NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data", "UninitializedEvaluationNet"]` (Actually turns out you'll need to adapt it. MNIST is only 1-9)

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes,in my case,it will over 9.And it is not handwriting.

Comment: You can pretty easily adapt LeNet to that, though (that's what I did). I'm sure with a bigger set of images you can get better results than my answer.

Comment: @b3m2a1 If the model is overfit,then even you train it with a bigger set,it will not be better I think(I just guess so)..

Answer (score 2):

So I pulled a net pretty much straight from here:

```
NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data", "ConstructionNotebook"]
```

What it ended looking like was:

```
nm =
  NetChain[{
    ConvolutionLayer[20, {5, 5}],
    ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
    PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, {2, 2}],
    ConvolutionLayer[50, {5, 5}],
    ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
    PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, {2, 2}],
    FlattenLayer[],
    DotPlusLayer[500],
    ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
    LinearLayer[22],
    SoftmaxLayer[]
    },
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[0, 21]}],
   "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}]
   ];
```

All I changed was the `LinearLayer[22]` and the `Range[0, 21]`.

Then:

```
data = RandomSample[
   Catenate[
    Thread /@ 
     Tuples[Function[font, 
         Image[Rasterize[Style[ToString[#], FontFamily -> font], 
             ImageResolution -> 150]] & /@ Range[21]] /@ 
        RandomSample[$FontFamilies, 10] -> {Range[21]}]]
   ];

trained = NetTrain[nm, Take[data, 150]];

Association[Reverse /@ Take[data, {151, -1}]] // Map[trained]

<|16 -> 16, 4 -> 4, 13 -> 13, 11 -> 21, 17 -> 17, 12 -> 12, 1 -> 1, 
 6 -> 5, 15 -> 14, 21 -> 21, 19 -> 19, 18 -> 19, 7 -> 7, 10 -> 16, 
 2 -> 2, 20 -> 20, 14 -> 14, 3 -> 3, 5 -> 5, 9 -> 9|>
```

(Note the attempted separation of test set and training set)

All in all that's pretty good.

Comment: When I set a `ValidationSet`,it don't converge like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ9u1.png). I mean it it overfit.It is not a good model..

Comment: @yode Ah too bad. Well maybe the model can be adapted, but I don't really know enough to say how. I was mostly interested showing how LeNet could be switched up for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Only add a `SoftmaxLayer[]` layer,then it's OK

```
net = NetInitialize@NetChain[{ImageAugmentationLayer[{12, 12}, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {15, 15}}], "Output" -> NetDecoder["Image"]], FlattenLayer[], 
                              21, 
                              SoftmaxLayer[]}, 
                             "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[21]}]]
```

Because of `SoftmaxLayer[][lis]` will make the output represent probability.

And the net is too simple,`lenet` based on `CNN` will help improve the result

Comment: That mean you can train your `net` now?